# Convert PHP Array to JSON object with UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following PHP code which pulls the data form mysql (unicode entries)

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mapping") or die ("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$sql = "select * from villages";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("error" . mysqli_error($conn));
$myArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $myArray[] = $row;
}
mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

?>
```

$myArray[0] is:

```
{"id":"1","village":"अकबरपुर","villageEn":"akbarpur","subdiv":"हुजूर","tehsil":"हुजूर","ricircle":"रातीबढ़","patwarih":"अकबरपुर"}
```

When I do console.log() all the array items are shown in  at once, what I want is to view them as objects[javascript (aka JSON)] in browser devtools

Comment: You already converted it. What's your question?

Comment: Browser devtools not showing objects; if it is already converted how do i display all villages using object call?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "display using object call".

Comment: Do you mean: "I want to use it in javascript as object"?

Comment: Browser devtools is showing whole data of array in a <body> not showing object view like object1{village.. subdiv...}..object2.. etc.

Comment: yes @Jeff that's what I want

Comment: @Anas please extract the relevant information from your comments and include them in your question via edit.  Future readers will want to get the full story from reading the question alone, not from expanding the comments and reading each persons' thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use the json in javascript you can simply do that:
(I suppose you call that php file directly, not via an ajax call!)

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mapping") or die ("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$sql = "select * from villages";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("error" . mysqli_error($conn));
$myArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $myArray[] = $row;
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
<script>
// here's the trick!
var villages = <?php echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>;
console.log(villages);
</script>
```

If you use it via an ajax call check out @julekgwa's answer!

Answer (score 4):

Try this one to print in browser devtools :

```
$myArray = json_encode($myArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo 'village : '.$myArray['village'];
echo 'subdiv : '.$myArray['subdiv'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.parse()` in your javascript (using `jQuery`).

```
//assuming that you are using ajax
$.post('get_villages.php', function(data) {
   var villages = JSON.parse(data);
   for (var village in villages) {
       console.log(village.id + ' ' + village.village + ' ' + village.villageEng);
   }
});
```